# Aggregate columns but distinct terms should be inserted

Tags: oracle, distinct, aggregate, string-aggregation

I have two table and I want to merge them

```
TERMS_TABLE

 ID  | TERMS
 309 | 'hardware'
 309 | 'software'
 309 | 'computer'



TFIDF_TABLE

  ID | TERMS
 309 |'computer,phone,mp3....'
```

Now I want to add TERMS column of `TERMS_TABLE` to terms column of `TFIDF_TABLE` but If TFIDF_TABLE already contains  TERMS of TERMS_TABLE then I should not insert this term to the NEW_TFIDF_TABLE , like that

result should be:

```
NEW_TFIDF_TABLE

  ID | TERMS
 309 |'computer,phone,mp3....,hardware,software'
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Oracle 11 you can try this:

```
select t3.id, t3.terms||','||t4.terms terms from 
(
select t1.id, listagg(t1.terms,',') within group (order by t1.terms)  terms
from terms_table t1 join tfidf_table t2 on  t1.id=t2.id
where instr(t2.terms,t1.terms)=0 
group by t1.id ) 
t3 right outer join tfidf_table  t4 on t3.id=t4.id
```

On Oracle 10 you could try

```
select t3.id, t3.terms||','||t4.terms terms from 
(
select t1.id, wm_concat(t1.terms)  terms
from terms_table t1 join tfidf_table t2 on  t1.id=t2.id
where instr(t2.terms,t1.terms)=0 
group by t1.id ) 
t3 right outer join tfidf_table  t4 on t3.id=t4.id
```

Comment: Why are there 4 table t1, t2, t3, t4?  I have only two table and a result table